# c# Code : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' please see my code

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

These codes aren't running.When inside the nested loop I'm trying to assign integer value on totalMembers[j] array index , the compiler throws mentioned exeption.please help so that this program can run.

```
        int totalHours = 0, memArraySize = 0;
        int[] totalMembers = new int[memArraySize];
        int[] memHours = new int[memArraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var stringNumbers = Console.ReadLine();
            var numbers = stringNumbers.Split(' ');
            int.TryParse(numbers[0], out totalHours);
            int.TryParse(numbers[1], out memArraySize);

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                totalMembers[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                memHours[i] = memHours[i] + totalMembers[j];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int totalHours, memArraySize;
    int[] totalMembers;
    int[] memHours;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var stringNumbers = Console.ReadLine();
        var numbers = stringNumbers.Split(' ');
        int.TryParse(numbers[0], out totalHours);
        int.TryParse(numbers[1], out memArraySize);
        totalMembers = new int[memArraySize];
        memHours = new int[memArraySize];
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            totalMembers[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            memHours[i] = memHours[i] + totalMembers[j];
        }

    }
```

so that the arrays totalMembers and memHours can contain values.

Comment: I took input here,  int.TryParse(numbers[1], out memArraySize);

Comment: Move these two lines after you take the input

int[] totalMembers = new int[memArraySize];
        int[] memHours = new int[memArraySize];

Comment: please try to run the code.Everything as you said.thanks